# Operation of a 74LS191 Counter

Tags: counter

I would like to confirm if the implementation of my 74LS191 counter is correct. Here is a diagram of my circuit:

[image]

The purpose of the circuit is to count from binary 0011 to binary 1111. However, the circuit above only counts from 0011 to 1110. After 1110 it recycles back to 0011. My expectation is that it would reach 1111 and then recycle back to 0011. Is this the normal operation of the 74LS191, or am I missing something?

Comment: It does reach 1111  for a few nano-seconds (or however long it takes to reset the counter).

Comment: @brhans Yes, I did actually notice this

Comment: So it seems that you should either reset on 0000 instead or use more logic and/or a flip-flop/latch to gate the reset signal using the clock line. I'm not intimately familiar with the '191 so I'm just throwing out suggestions here ...

Comment: You can probably get a 74LS02 so you don't have to mix LS and F logic. (not that it won't work 95% of the time, but F series has a bad reputation for causing trouble due to being *too* fast)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. But I need to stick with what's given, as this is a practical assignment.

Comment: If this is a practical assignment, you need to be aware that a floating input (as in your up/down pin and clock) will not default to 0. 7400/LS/S/F/etc will show a floating input as a 1, with the proviso that it is susceptible to noise pickup. The traditional way is to pull up the input with a 1k to 10k, then use the switch to short to ground for a 0. And if you ever try a floating input with CMOS, you'll learn what heartbreak really means.

Answer (score 1):

Using external 4 input NAND for LOAD! is a bad design for race conditions, as it should also include CLK! to occur mid-cycle when a race condition is avoided.

For this reason, RCO! should be used instead,to drive LOAD!.